# fluent NHibernate one-to-one relationship?

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have a problem with one-to-one relationships in the fluent nHibernate.

I have the following relational table from the AdventureWorks2008 database.

```
BusinessEntity (Table)
    BusinessEntityId Int (PK, Identity)

Person (Table)
   BusinessEntityId int (PK, Reference with BusinessEntity table)
   FullName varchar(255)
```

The relationship between BusinessEntity table and Person table is one-to-one.

How do I map fluently without any extra field like "Id" in the Person table?

There should be 2 class one for Person and another for BusinessEntity, or an appropriate model to best describe the above relation.

Thanks,
Ashraf.

Comment: How are your model classes setup?

Comment: There should be 2 class one for Person and another for BusinessEntity. or an appropriate model. example 
public class Person { public virtual BusinessEntity BusinessEntity { get; set; } public virtual string Description { get; set; } }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

presuming your Person mapping is pretty standard, the way you do this is by saying:

```
Id(x => x.BusinessEntityId)
     .GeneratedBy.Foreign("BusinessEntity");
```

on the Person class.

This presumes that your Person class has a property called BusinessEntity which is of type BusinessEntity.

You'll also need to map BusinessEntity to Person with constrained set to true (to say that they primary key of Person is a foreign key reference to BusinessEntity).

The key thing is the GeneratedBy.Foreign() to say that your identity is generated by a link to another class.